# How do I add no-cache to Kestrel responses?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm using Asp.Net Core RC2 and Kestrel as my web server. I need to ensure that requests (in this case all of them) are responded to with a no-cache header so that the browsers get the newest version (not 304).

Is there a way in Startup to configure Kestrel or a way to inject this step into the pipeline?

EDIT: no-store may be a better choice in my situation: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching "no-store  Response is not allowed to be cached and must be fetched in full on every request."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use middleware to work with headers. For example, you can force no-cache cache-control by adding the following to the top of your Startup's Configure method:

```
app.Use(async (httpContext, next) =>
{
    httpContext.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "no-cache";
    await next();
});
```

Comment: nit: you can use the built-in [`HeaderNames` class](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/release/src/Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers/HeaderNames.cs) to avoid the first magic string: `httpContext.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "no-cache"`.

Comment: Updated to reflect change.

Comment: Make sure this is above other app.Uses (ex app.UseDefaultFiles or app.UseStaticFiles()

Comment: @Aligned thank you, potentially saved me a half an hour of debugging.